# Frequent java.lang.AssertionError on Cassandra startup

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Setup

We were running Cassandra 3.7 in a standalone mode as a service and as root. This is our cassandra evaluation phase and we did not seem to have any problems for quite some time . but around last week we started seeing intermittently the following errors

```
ERROR [main] 2017-02-02 21:54:58,854 CassandraDaemon.java:731 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.Throwables.maybeFail(Throwables.java:50) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFutures(FBUtilities.java:372) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.blockForWrites(CommitLogReplayer.java:257) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:186) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:165) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:314) [apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:585) [apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:714) [apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFutures(FBUtilities.java:365) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache$CachingRebufferer.<init>(ChunkCache.java:202) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache.wrap(ChunkCache.java:155) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache.maybeWrap(ChunkCache.java:163) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedSegmentedFile.createRebufferer(BufferedSegmentedFile.java:42) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedSegmentedFile.<init>(BufferedSegmentedFile.java:27) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedSegmentedFile$Builder.complete(BufferedSegmentedFile.java:50) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$Builder.complete(SegmentedFile.java:181) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$Builder.buildIndex(SegmentedFile.java:207) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.openFinal(BigTableWriter.java:309) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.access$600(BigTableWriter.java:55) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter$TransactionalProxy.doPrepare(BigTableWriter.java:348) ~[apache-cassandra-]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.prepareToCommit(Transactional.java:173) ~[apache-cassandr]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.prepareToCommit(SSTableWriter.java:275) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.prepareToCommit(SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.java:101) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.flushMemtable(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1148) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1098) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

On digging up a bit, we came across similar bugs that were raised and fixed in cassandra 2.x e.g [Node Startup fails with assertionerror](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204612069-Node-startup-fails-with-java-lang-AssertionError-while-reading-saved-cache). But these solutions do not seem to solve our issues.A crude solution that we followed was , that we delete the data directory, and cassandra recreates it and comes up correctly. However, this is not a panacea for our problems.

Questions : 
1) What is the reason for this error . I can only see that this is something with respect to caches , but my saved_cache_directory is empty.

2) Is there some configurations that we are overlooking . Are there any specific configurations with respect to caching that have to be done in cassandra.yaml

Comment: There is no need to delete the data directory, as far as I can tell one of the commit logs is broken, so you would just need to remove one specific commit log in order for the node to start up. What worries me a bit is that there are multiple cassandra versions running on same machine (If I got it right) so there might also be issues with two cassandra concurrently doing stuff with commit logs.

Comment: Thank you for the comment . We have migrated everything to cassandra 3.7 now . and that is the only version running. However, how do we deal with broken commit logs. i tried nodetool flush . but that doesnt seem to fix the problem .

Comment: Correct, nodetool flush will move the tables to disk and dispose commit log. If you are shutting down I would go with nodetool drain ... yes flush will move the memtable to disk, but new writes will still come to commit log. Also consider running 3.7. LTS https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra

Comment: Personally I wouldn't go with never version of cassandra than datastax is running for their commercial offering. http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/RNcassChanges.html#RNcassFixes__505 (3.0.11)

Comment: Thanks a lot . I did'nt know about 3.7 long term support . Will surely check that out for testing . probably also experiment with 3.0.11 .  Thanks a lot for giving a new direction